# How to display python list values in form using table in odoo 9

Tags: jquery, xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

I have set of values in python list, And I want to display the values in forms using table

Python code:

```
@api.model
def get_models(self):
    models_list =[]
    model_obj = ''
    models_list1 = []
    gs_configuration_obj = self.env['ir.model']
    for sco_search in gs_configuration_obj.search([]):
     for sco_obj in gs_configuration_obj.browse(sco_search.name):
        models_list += sco_obj
    user_models_list = [x[0] for x in models_list]
    models_list = sorted(list(set(user_models_list)))
    for m in models_list:
       print m
    return models_list
```

Now I have to display the list values in form as a table.

Thanks